# Windows Server 2016 Not Showing any Text in Properties Box

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2016

I am having an issue with my new fresh Windows Server 2016 install

The server is a, HP Proliate DL360 Gen5

I was trying to set a static ip on the server but when i clicked on the properties section of the network settings, the box came up and was blank...

There was buttons but they had no text and there was just not any text in the whole window

Network Properties: 
[image: Network Properties]

Answer (score 0):

You can check your installation with dism (/Cleanup-Image) and sfc. Maybe you have installed a software on your server which have caused the problem. Or your installation had problems.
But you say, that it is fresh installed. So I think you have not done mush after the installation?!

But this looks really wired. When you can you should at best reinstall your server, when the problem persist. Also check your installation media.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)